# PHP find specific values inside of table(file)?

Tags: php

I have a file table.html and would like to get this values: $age, $height, $weight

table.html:

```
<tr><td class="key">Age</td><td class="value">24</td></tr>
<tr><td class="key">Height</td><td class="value">169</td></tr>
<tr><td class="key">Weight</td><td class="value">51</td></tr>
```

*So far I have made this code:*

```
$html = file_get_contents("table.html");

libxml_use_internal_errors( true);
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML( $html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc);

// A name attribute on a <td>
$age = $xpath->query( '//td[@class="key"]')->item( 0);

echo $age->textContent;
```

The "**echo**" result of $age is **Age** but I want it to be **24**

How can I get Height and Weight results in same code?

Comment: Does `@class="value"` not work?

Comment: class="value" works. But in some cases if the Height value is empty then the Weight will show as Height.

Comment: @Cyborg: What do you want to do if one of elements (say Height) is not present in the table? Do you want to display the rest of the quantities? Or something like `Height: undefined`?

Comment: @AmalMurali: Yes, if element Height dosen't exists then I don't want to show it and process all other elements.

Answer (score 2):

The class name you want is `value`, not `key`, so you'll need to modify the XPath expression accordingly:

```
$result = $xpath->query( '//td[@class="value"]');

$age = $result->item(0)->textContent;
$height = $result->item(1)->textContent;
$weight = $result->item(2)->textContent;
```

Note that I've removed the two additional XPath calls. As Jonathan notes in the comments below, one call is enough, and the rest of the items can be retrieved from the resulting NodeList.

As for outputting the retrieved values, you can simply use `echo`, with `isset()`. This is to make sure you only echo the quantities if they're set:

```
echo (isset($age)) ? "Age: $age\n" : '';
echo (isset($age)) ? "Height: $height\n" : '';
echo (isset($age)) ? "Weight: $weight\n" : '';
```

The above code should produce:

```
Age: 24
Height: 169
Weight: 51
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/54360)

---

**UPDATE**

As you noted in the comments, this will fail if one of the `<tr>` blocks is not present. In that case, you could simply use a `foreach` loop to display the items:

```
$quantities = $xpath->query( '//td[@class="key"]');
$values = $xpath->query('//td[@class="value"]');

foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
    echo $quantities->item($key)->textContent .' = '. $value->textContent."\n";
}
```

This will return the correct results, even when one (or more) `<tr>` tags are absent. It'll print out whatever values are in there.

For example, if the Height row is missing, then it'd output:

```
Age = 24
Weight = 51
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/54413)

Comment: What if the Height value is EMPTY?

Comment: @Cyborg: If it's empty, the value won't be displayed. If you want to make sure it's not empty, you can do `if(isset($height)) { // echo value }` and similar.

Comment: You shouldn't query three times; just once should be fine. You can then grab the items from the resulting NodeList.

Comment: @JonathanSampson: You're right. I've edited the answer to reflect that, thanks :)

Comment: @Cyborg: If the height value is empty, it won't be displayed. You can check this by removing the height element from your HTML table. I'm not sure if that's what you were asking, but if not -- could you explain in more detail?

Comment: Amal: You are right, but the problems is if the entire HTML row: **<tr><td class="key">Height</td><td class="value">169</td></tr>** dosent exist then Weight will show as Height cause Weight will then be ->item( 1); In that case its better to use //td[text()="Height"]')->item( 0); as @Jack suggested. Is it any other ways to do it?

Comment: @AmalMurali: Thats a good idea to foreach all values with this short code. This will return ALL values inside that table, what if I have all values but want to echo ONLY **Age**?

Comment: Is it possible to use something like: `if(isset($height)) { // echo value }` with this updated code?

Answer (score 0):

Providing you know the definate structure of the file, something like this will work; using `->nextSibling`, and `->item(i)`, etc.

```
$html = file_get_contents("table.html");

libxml_use_internal_errors( true);
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML( $html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc);

// A name attribute on a <td>
$age     = $xpath->query( '//td[@class="key"]')->item( 0);
$height  = $xpath->query( '//td[@class="key"]')->item( 1);
$weight  = $xpath->query( '//td[@class="key"]')->item( 2);

echo "\nAge: "    . $age->nextSibling->textContent;
echo "\nHeight: " . $height->nextSibling->textContent;
echo "\nWeight: " . $weight->nextSibling->textContent;
```

And the output would be:

```
Age: 24
Height: 169
Weight: 51
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/54349)**

Also works with blank values.

**EDIT;**

Another way of doing this is to get the element by its text content.

```
$html = file_get_contents("table.html");

libxml_use_internal_errors( true);
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML( $html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath( $doc);

// A name attribute on a <td>
$age     = $xpath->query( '//td[text()="Age"]')->item( 0);
$height  = $xpath->query( '//td[text()="Height"]')->item( 0);
$weight  = $xpath->query( '//td[text()="Weight"]')->item( 0);

echo "\nAge: "    . $age->nextSibling->textContent;
echo "\nHeight: " . $height->nextSibling->textContent;
echo "\nWeight: " . $weight->nextSibling->textContent;
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/54356)**

Comment: What do you mean by *Also works with blank values.*?

Comment: The OP posted a comment on your answer stating "What if the Height value is EMPTY?". It simply states that if the value is blank, it will continue to work.

Comment: @Jack Is it possible to replace **//td[@class="key"]** with **<tr><td class="key">Age</td><td class="value">** ? Cause then I can avoid item( 0), item( 1) and item( 2) and I will be 100% sure that the value is Age

Comment: @JackB: Same with my solution. The code will execute fine, the value of Height will just be empty.

Comment: You can change the xpath query to select the element by named (for example, changing it to `//td[text()="Age"]`) but you cannot remove the `->item(0)` as this is the way the results are returned. Example: https://eval.in/54356

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
foreach (array('age', 'height', 'weight') as $key => $value) {
    $result[$value] = $xpath->query( '//td[@class="value"]')->item($key)->textContent;
}

print_r($result);
```